# idlj.exe : file not found exception

Tags: java, networking, corba, idl

I'm running the following command through CMD:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\idlj.exe" -fall hello.idl
```

The hello.idl file is located in the same folder as the idlj.exe file and contains the following

```
module HelloApp
{
interface Hello
{
string sayHello();
oneway void shutdown();
};
};
```

However, I am receiving the following error upon execution of the above command:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hello.idl (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Can you please advise what is wrong here and the solution. Should the idl file be located in another folder?

Thanks

Comment: looks like `hello.idl` is not located in the _current_ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file hello.idl should be in your current directory.

So if you have the idl file in the same dir like `idlj.exe`, then you should go to directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` and execute the command: `idlj.exe -fall hello.idl`